# How to change the class loader in the application.xml file to support preference loading of deployed jars

Tags: ant, websphere

I have built a web app using Tomcat 6 as a container.  I was using a couple of Jars of Tomcat's and referring to them from my ant build in Eclipse.

I've written another ant build to deploy my app into a .war and then together with an application.xml deployment descriptor into an .ear for deploying to WAS 7.  In order to support this, I've pulled the jars into my war so I know they'll be available to the app which worked through Tomcat.

I know that I need to put something into the application.xml file to cause the class loader to use the jars I've pulled in and not WAS's but for the life of me I can't even find a decent resource to read up on what full range of options exist in an application.xml file let alone exactly what I need to type to put this (PARENT_LAST?) text in.

1) Can anyone point me to a full online document listing all the things that I can put into my application.xml to control my .ear

2) Can anyone post a listing which modifies the below xml such that when the xml file is included in a .ear it can deploy to WAS such that the WAS container uses the jars in the enclosed war rather than the ones in the WAS setup.

I will be eternally grateful.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Client">
   <display-name>Client</display-name>
   <description>Web application supporting the configuration and management of server components</description>
   <module id="Client">
      <web>
         <web-uri>Client.war</web-uri>
         <context-root>client</context-root>
      </web>
   </module> 
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PARENT_LAST` is not likely to help you, not to mention that I wouldn't touch that option with a 10-foot pole as I always considered it a hack.

The behavior you're looking for is provided by default - that's actually the "correct" way of working according to the J2EE spec. Can you provide us with the exact composition of your EAR file, your WAR file, and the `MANIFEST.MF` file of both?

[Edited to add the following]

The comment below is correct as well (thanks) - if you included JAR files from Tomcat inside your Web application, then you're already doing something very wrong and most likely unportable.

- JAR files pertaining to the J2EE specification (such as JAR files containing the J2EE API) are provided by application server vendors; you should exclude them from your deployable module (EAR, WAR).
- JAR files pertaining to specific Tomcat functionality... Well, those wouldn't function outside of Tomcat so the entire subject of WebSphere migration is moot.

Comment: Under the circumstances, the answer is correct.  Don't do it.  I've learned the hard way to never pull jars from one app server for use in another.